# Derivative of $ y = arctg \sqrt{x} $

Tags: derivatives

My solution is $ \frac{1}{1+x} \ast  \frac{1}{2}\ast x^{-\frac{1}{2}} $. Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: Edited a mistype in my solution.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. $y' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(x+1)}$